# How to select one row if condition true, all rows if condition false in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, relational-database

Suppose there is a table

temp

col1  |  col ----

100   | c

456   | c1

131   |c2

--

suppose I have coll1 = 100 means a valid row query have to return only the row
if value does not exists in table query have to return all row from table.

Note: We can not use if exists or any procedural thing (only SQL no TSQL)

We cannot use below

```
   if exists( select 1 from temp where col1=100)

      begin
         select 1 from temp where col1=100 
     end
  else 
     begin
        select  * from temp where col1=100 
     end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with just using `not exists`:

```
SELECT *
FROM temp t
WHERE col1 = 100 
    OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM temp 
                   WHERE col1 = 100);
```

- [Condensed Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b7598b/2)

Answer (score 1):

```
$qry1="Select Col1 from table where col1=100";
$res1 = mysql_query($qry1);
if(row_count($res)>0){
/* Process data*/
}
else{
$qry2="Select * from table where col1=100";
$res2 = mysql_query($qry2);
/*process data*/
}
```

Comment: We have precondition we can not use if block and only sql